# Puedo usar una configuración universal para tres aplicaciones de Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, hibernate, mvc

Supongamos que se tienen las Aplicaciones Web A. B y C. Cada una de ellas tiene los siguientes XML:

1. applicationContext.xml
2. hibernateConfiguration.xml (Configuración de DataSource, SessionFactory, etc..)
3. securityConfiguration.xml (Interceptores, COnfiguracion LDAP, etc...)
4. springConfiguration.xml (ViewResolver, MultipartResolver, etc...)

Quisiera saber si se puede hacer una configuración única para estas tres Aplicaciones Web, es decir, que A, B y C usen la misma configuración descrita en los puntos anteriores.

¿Por que quiero hacer esto? En cada una de ellas creo un SessionFactory y hago uso de Hibernate, mi principal preocupación es que caiga en un Deadlock, soy novato.

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes 3 aplicaciones web diferentes A,B y C no puedes ni es necesario que compartan los mismos contextos.

Si las tres aplicaciones van a acceder a datos comunes plantea la posibilidad de tener servicios comunes con acceso rest por ejemplo de manera que desacoplas y evitas posibles deadlock.

En caso de tirar por esta solución existen te recomiendo que revises las diversas estrategias de acceso a datos de manera concurrente. JPA 2 soporte tanto bloqueo optimista como pesimista.

Te adjunto enlace donde puedes consultar estos tipos de estrategias que existen para acceso concurrente a la información mediante JPA. En el caso de usar otro ORM como Hibernate, como comentas, es similar.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/es-ES/html/transactions.html